# UpdatePanel issue when using javascript only controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, updatepanel, fine-uploader

Included below is my markup for a page I have using a FineUploader control.  I've abridged the  code to only include the important parts.  This page is two parts that both reside in an UpdatePanel.  The first part is a simple table that contains rows of data, the last column of each row is a asp:LinkButton.  The second part is a nested UpdatePanel that contains a div in which the FineUploader control is rendered when the page is first loaded (because the FineUploader control is strictly javascript and does not further exist in the code-behind).  Also, when the LinkButton is pressed `this.Page.IsPostBack` is `false`.

The problem is that any time a LinkButton in the first part of the page is pressed, the FineUploader control simply disappears.  I cannot get the code to re-render from the code-behind (with things like `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript/RegisterClientScriptBlock`).  I've also tried various setups with wrapping Part 1 with an UpdatePanel but still it wipes out my FineUploader control.  I'm thinking I'm using update panels incorrectly, but am not sure (ASP.NET is not usually what I work in).

As an added detail, if I click a button inside the Part 2 nested UpdatePanel, my FineUploader control magically reappears.

Markup (for visibility important parts are marked with multi-line, mostly empty comment blocks):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Setup.aspx.cs" Inherits="Some_Portal.Pages.Setup" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
   <div id="locationInfo">
      <br class="clearfloat" />
      <!-- Main Screen Display breaking down the types of information -->
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updExtensions">
      <Triggers>
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDownloadCall" />
      </Triggers>
         <ContentTemplate>

         <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    .filename {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
}
  </style>

<!-- This portion is to enable the file uploader: -->
<link href="../js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
         element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
         request: {
            endpoint: 'AccountSetup.aspx'
         },
         autoUpload: true,
         multiple: false,
         text: {
            uploadButton: '<asp:Button ID="fineUploadButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" style="width:6;5" Text="Browse" />'
         },
         validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['mp3', 'wav']
         }
      });
   });
</script>


            <!--                             -->
            <!--                             -->
            <!--           Part 1            -->
            <!--                             -->
            <!--                             -->
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" border="0px" style="border-color:white;">
               <tr>
                  <th>Extensions</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td style="width: 100%; border:0; border-bottom-color:white; border-bottom-style:none;">
                     <asp:DataGrid ID="dgExtensions" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-BorderStyle="None"  PagerStyle-BorderColor="white" PagerStyle-BorderWidth="0px"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="10" DataKeyField="id" OnPageIndexChanged="dgExtensions_OnPageIndexChanged"
                        PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" OnSortCommand="dgExtensions_OnSortCommand"                        
                        Width="100%" BorderColor="White"
                     HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" 
                      ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem"
                     AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="GridAltItem">
                        <Columns>
                           <asp:BoundColumn DataField="number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="number">
                              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="8%" />
                              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="8%" />
                           </asp:BoundColumn>
                           <asp:BoundColumn DataField="extensionType" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="extensionType">
                              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="18%" />
                              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="18%" />
                           </asp:BoundColumn>
                           <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description">
                              <HeaderStyle Width="25%" CssClass="dgLeftPad" />
                              <ItemStyle Width="25%" CssClass="dgLeftPad" />
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Literal runat="Server" ID="litExtensionDescription" Text='<%# Eval("description").ToString() %>' />
                                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidExtensionID" Value='<%# Eval("id").ToString() %>' />
                                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidExtensionTypeID" Value='<%# Eval("extensiontypeid").ToString() %>' />
                                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidPrevDescription" Value='<%# Eval("description").ToString() %>' />
                              </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateColumn>
                           <asp:BoundColumn DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status">
                              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="24%" />
                              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="24%" />
                           </asp:BoundColumn>                       
                           <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
                              <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                              <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                 <!--                              -->
                                 <!--                              -->
                                 <!-- Clicking this makes the Fine -->
                                 <!-- Uploader control go away.    -->
                                 <!--                              -->
                                 <!--                              -->
                                 <asp:LinkButton runat="Server" ID="lbEditExtension" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id").ToString() %>'
                                    OnCommand="EditExtension" Text="Edit" Visible='<%# SetEditEnabled(Eval("extensiontypeid").ToString()) %>'/>
                              </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#eeeeee" />
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Mode="NumericPages" />
                     </asp:DataGrid>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNoExtensions">
                     <td colspan="3" align="center" style="color: Red;">
                        There are no extensions established for your account
                     </td>
                  </asp:Panel>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <br />


            <!--                             -->
            <!--                             -->
            <!--           Part 2            -->
            <!--                             -->
            <!--                             -->
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Width="100%">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updRouteGroup" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDisableOnHold" />
              </Triggers>
              <ContentTemplate>        
               <asp:Panel ID="pnlImpExcel" runat="Server" >
              <div style="width:100%">
               <table colspan="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                     <th colspan="3">
                        On Hold Music
                     </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <!--                             -->
                     <!--   FineUploader Control      -->
                     <!--                             -->
                     <td align="left" valign="middle"><div id="fine-uploader"></div></td>
                     <td align="center" valign="middle"><asp:Label ID="lblOnHoldFile" runat="server" Text="Current file: none"/></td>
                     <td align="right" valign="middle"><asp:Button ID="btnDisableOnHold" runat="server" style="margin-right:7px;width:87px;" Text="Disable Hold Music" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnDisableOnHold_OnClick" /></td>
                  </tr>               
                  <tr><td colspan ="2" align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUploadError" style="color: Red;" Visible="false" /></td></tr>
               </table> 
               </div>

               </asp:Panel> 
               </ContentTemplate> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel> 
            </asp:Panel>

            <!-- The Operator Extension Panel -->
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOperatorUpdate" />
              </Triggers>

              <ContentTemplate>        
               <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="Server" >
              <div>
               <table colspan="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                     <th colspan="3">
                        Operator Extension
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOperatorUpdate" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="button" style="margin-right:2px;width:87px;float:right;padding-right:10px;" OnClick="btnOperatorUpdate_OnClick" />                        
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="Server" ID="ddlOperatorExtension" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="false" />
                     </th>
                  </tr>                  
               </table> 
               <br />
               </div>
               </asp:Panel> 
               </ContentTemplate> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel> 
            </asp:Panel>



         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I make my FineUploader control stay visible?

EDIT 1:
Considering this might be a page life cycle issue, I attempted a manual render of the control by adding the following:

```
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                        "   alert('oh hey');" + 
                        "   $(document).ready(function () {" +
                        "      var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({" +
                        "         element: $('#fine-uploader')[0]," +
                        "         request: {" +
                        "            endpoint: 'AccountSetup.aspx'" +
                        "         }," +
                        "         autoUpload: true," +
                        "         multiple: false," +
                        "         text: {" +
                        "            uploadButton: '<asp:Button ID=\"fineUploadButton\" runat=\"server\" CssClass=\"button\" style=\"width:6;5\" Text=\"Browse\" />'" +
                        "         }," +
                        "         validation: {" +
                        "            allowedExtensions: ['mp3', 'wav']" +
                        "         }" +
                        "      });" +
                        "   });" +
                        "</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "HideOnPostback", script, false);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page_Init() run");
  }
```

The result was that if I click the "Edit" LinkButton in Part 1, I see "Page_Init() run" in debug output, but the control still goes away and the "oh hey" js alert is never displayed.  However, if I click the other button in Part 2, I see "Page_Init() run" in the debug output, I see the "oh hey" alert and the FineUploader button remains visible.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are experiencing this issue because you are loading the FineUploader control too late in the page lifecycle for it to properly load the ViewState.  Clicking the button is triggering a postback which restarts the lifecycle for the page.  ViewState is loaded before Page_Load() so try to add the control to the page during Page_Init() instead so that the ViewState can be loaded.

Comment: I tried this with the same results as when I put in in the `Page_Load`.  I've added much more detail in an edit to my original question.

Comment: Are you setting EnablePartialRendering="true" on your ScriptManager?  If you do, what happens if you wrap an update panel around Part 1's LinkButton?

Comment: Another possible hiccup is that the control ID needs to be the same when it is recreated.  It looks like you aren't having this issue but it might be worth checking if all else fails.

Comment: So I did wrap Par 1's LinkButton with a UpdatePanel (UpdateMode Conditional, if that matters), and I added the EnablePartialRendering detail to the ScriptManager.  Does it matter that the SM is in the Master Page?  Also, which control ID are you referring to about consistency?  THanks.

Comment: The Master Page is the proper place for the SM because you are only allowed one.  I am referring to the LinkButton's ID.  When it goes to load the ViewState after postback it checks for a control with the same ID and if the IDs are different it assumes it is a different control.